# How to multiply session values

Tags: php

I am trying to create a menu booking. if i select meal set 1 , the price is $100, meal set 2, the price is $200 and this selected value will multiple the amount of tables request 
below is my code but the price is showing $0 in total.

```
if($_POST['RadioGroup1'] == 'meal set 1')
      {
        $menuprice = '100';
      }
      else if ($_POST['RadioGroup1'] == 'meal set 2'){
        $menuprice = '200';
      }
     else if ($_POST['RadioGroup1'] == 'meal set 3'){

        $menuprice = '300';
     }

   //store the price of menu in session
    $_SESSION["pricemenu"] =$menuprice;
   ?>
```

// display the amount

```
<?php $_SESSION['total'] = ($_SESSION["pricemenu"] *           $_SESSION['nooftables']);
              echo $_SESSION['total'] ?><br>
```

Comment: Where do you set `$_SESSION['nooftables']`? Otherwise this will be 0 and your total will always be 0

Comment: Where is defined `$_SESSION['nooftables']`?

Comment: this is from the dropdown list which i didnt shown it here

Comment: the total amount now showing no matter which menu i select will show  no of table x $300

Comment: If it's from HTML form, the value isn't in session, but in `$_POST['nooftables']`.

Comment: Have you started your session using `session_start()`?

Comment: What do you get if you do `var_dump($_SESSION['pricemenu']);` and `var_dump($_SESSION['nooftables'])` just above your echo?

Comment: yes have put session_start()

Answer (score 0):

Put `$menuprice = '';` in front the if statement so that you make that global. You can't not take a string out of an if statement before making it global. I had this problem before and it actually work for me. Hope it help you.

Comment: hi which line do you mean?

Comment: $menuprice = ''; i put it in front of if statement but still same issue

Comment: Is your choice an radio button type? `$_POST['THE NAME OF THE OBJECT']`, `$_POST['RadioGroup1'] == 'meal set 1'` will give you an error because the syntax is already wrong. Can you turn on error reporting by adding this code to the top of your page? `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. It will make it easier for me and others.